# How to get Vi to insert a column of characters?

Tags: vi, macvim

If I have the following code where the dots (.) are spaces,

```
....def foobar():
........foo = x
........bar = y
```

how do I get Vim to insert a pound (#) and a single space in the same column on each row like this:

```
....#.def foobar():
....#.....foo = x
....#.....bar = y
```

I know I can hit ^v to enter column insert mode and then I can hit the "j" key twice to select the following two rows in that same column, but all the articles I've read on this say you should then hit the "I" key to enter insert mode.  However, when I do that, I only go into insert mode of the first line, not all three lines.  What am I missing?  Incidentally, I don't want to have to count the spaces and do a substitution command.  I know I can do that.  There has to be an easier way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
:1-3s/^.../^...#./
```

From lines 1 to 3 (adjust for your own purposes), replace (s command) three spaces at the start of the line by three spaces, a # and an extra space.

Comment: Thanks, but again, this isn't a good answer.  The solution should not require counting spaces.  There has to be a way to do this via Vi's column mode.

Answer (score 0):

Every command you`ll try there will modify the actual line, or a set of line doing a command (like the other answer shows).

The other way might be a substitution, like :

:map z /....ˆM4s...#ˆ[

(ˆM is CTRL-V M to sinalize an Enter, and ˆ[ is CTRL-V Escape, to end substitution)

After mapping 'z' you may press 'z'in each line you want.